# Alterar texto com Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,

Alguem poderia me ajudar com um script JS para alterar o texto do botão instantaneamente ?

Mas alterar somente quando o status da variavel $x mudar de 0 para 1, ou então quando clicar sobre o botão que contém o texto.

Comment: Falta colocar o código

Answer (score 0):

O rótulo do botão pode ser alterado ao clicar, dessa forma:

```
<button class="meu-botao">Clique aqui</button>

<script>
    (function($){
        var $botao = $('.meu-botao');

        //Ao clicar no botao
        $botao.on('click', function(e) { 
            $botao.html("Botão clicado");
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Alterar o rótulo do botão quando uma variável muda de valor, pode ser feito com [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set), mas é importante que essa variável faça parte de um objeto

```
<button class="meu-botao">Clique aqui</button>

<script>
    (function($){
        var $botao = $('.meu-botao');
        var $y = {valor: 0};
        var checarAlteracao = {
            set(obj, prop, valor) {
                var label = (valor > 0)? "Variável alterada": "Clique aqui";
                $botao.html(label);
                return Reflect.set(...arguments);
            }
        };

        //Altera no duplo clique do botão
        $botao.on('dblclick', function(e) {
            $x.valor++;
        });

        var $x = new Proxy($y, checarAlteracao);
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```